# Rails aborted! unknown binary format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I start `rails server` or `rake assets:precompile` I get this message

```
(rails or rake) aborted! unknown binary format.
```

I don't understand why. Where does the problem come from?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling ruby or the gems? what have you tried?

Comment: What version of rails?  What version of Ruby?  What operating system?

Comment: I tried `bundle update & bundle install`

Comment: Rails 6 + Ruby 2.6 + Windows 10